# No 'users' table in nova database

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, rdo

After successful installation of Openstack RDO in multiple hosts, the mysql database doesn't show any users in `nova`.

Command `SHOW TABLES;` in the database does not show `user` or `users` table.

```
    MariaDB [nova]> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_nova                             |
+--------------------------------------------+
| agent_builds                               |
| aggregate_hosts                            |
| aggregate_metadata                         |
| aggregates                                 |
| allocations                                |
| block_device_mapping                       |
| bw_usage_cache                             |
| cells                                      |
| certificates                               |
| compute_nodes                              |
| console_pools                              |
| consoles                                   |
| dns_domains                                |
| fixed_ips                                  |
| floating_ips                               |
| instance_actions                           |
| instance_actions_events                    |
| instance_extra                             |
| instance_faults                            |
| instance_group_member                      |
| instance_group_policy                      |
| instance_groups                            |
| instance_id_mappings                       |
| instance_info_caches                       |
| instance_metadata                          |
| instance_system_metadata                   |
| instance_type_extra_specs                  |
| instance_type_projects                     |
| instance_types                             |
| instances                                  |
| inventories                                |
| key_pairs                                  |
| migrate_version                            |
| migrations                                 |
| networks                                   |
| pci_devices                                |
| project_user_quotas                        |
| provider_fw_rules                          |
| quota_classes                              |
| quota_usages                               |
| quotas                                     |
| reservations                               |
| resource_provider_aggregates               |
| resource_providers                         |
| s3_images                                  |
| security_group_default_rules               |
| security_group_instance_association        |
| security_group_rules                       |
| security_groups                            |
| services                                   |
| shadow_agent_builds                        |
| shadow_aggregate_hosts                     |
| shadow_aggregate_metadata                  |
| shadow_aggregates                          |
| shadow_block_device_mapping                |
| shadow_bw_usage_cache                      |
| shadow_cells                               |
| shadow_certificates                        |
| shadow_compute_nodes                       |
| shadow_console_pools                       |
| shadow_consoles                            |
| shadow_dns_domains                         |
| shadow_fixed_ips                           |
| shadow_floating_ips                        |
| shadow_instance_actions                    |
| shadow_instance_actions_events             |
| shadow_instance_extra                      |
| shadow_instance_faults                     |
| shadow_instance_group_member               |
| shadow_instance_group_policy               |
| shadow_instance_groups                     |
| shadow_instance_id_mappings                |
| shadow_instance_info_caches                |
| shadow_instance_metadata                   |
| shadow_instance_system_metadata            |
| shadow_instance_type_extra_specs           |
| shadow_instance_type_projects              |
| shadow_instance_types                      |
| shadow_instances                           |
| shadow_key_pairs                           |
| shadow_migrate_version                     |
| shadow_migrations                          |
| shadow_networks                            |
| shadow_pci_devices                         |
| shadow_project_user_quotas                 |
| shadow_provider_fw_rules                   |
| shadow_quota_classes                       |
| shadow_quota_usages                        |
| shadow_quotas                              |
| shadow_reservations                        |
| shadow_s3_images                           |
| shadow_security_group_default_rules        |
| shadow_security_group_instance_association |
| shadow_security_group_rules                |
| shadow_security_groups                     |
| shadow_services                            |
| shadow_snapshot_id_mappings                |
| shadow_snapshots                           |
| shadow_task_log                            |
| shadow_virtual_interfaces                  |
| shadow_volume_id_mappings                  |
| shadow_volume_usage_cache                  |
| snapshot_id_mappings                       |
| snapshots                                  |
| tags                                       |
| task_log                                   |
| virtual_interfaces                         |
| volume_id_mappings                         |
| volume_usage_cache                         |
+--------------------------------------------+
109 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` table is in keystone database and not in nova database.

```
MariaDB [keystone]> show tables;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_keystone     |
+------------------------+
..........................
| trust                  |
| trust_role             |
| user                   |
..........................
```

Comment: I had this misconception by reading in a blog. Maybe `user` table was previously in `nova` database. I was stuck with the idea that there is something gone wrong in my setup that I didn't bother to check `keystone` database. Thanks for clearing it up.